# AutoRotate does not work iOS 9 & xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rotation, info.plist

I have stopped auto rotation.But now i want to  enable auto rotation . i did not enable it .How i enable auto rotation using info.plist ios 9 & xcode 7.Please help me .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your info.plist as source code. Remove existing entries and add these.

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Comment: i replaced this code  with my previous code of  info.plist. if you have any confusion ,then first remove auto rotate .Then try to add and let see what happen .

Answer (score 0):

Goto Project Target -> General -> Deployment info and mark check on all the orientations you want to include in your app

[image]